# AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment variables do not update from config file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When updating my env var values from an `.ebextensions/env-var.config` file, the env var is not updated within my environment. If I add a new env var to the config file it gets added to the environment as expected.

Original `env-var.config` file

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    VAR1=foo
    VAR2=bar
```

Running `eb printenv` will return me `foo` and `bar` for these two env vars. If I update the config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    VAR1=test
    VAR2=bar
    VAR3=new
```

Running `eb printenv` will return me:

```
VAR1 = foo
VAR2 = bar
VAR3 = new
```

How can I update environment variables from the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any already set environment variables will retain their values. If you want to change their values, you can either go to console and change it there under `software configuration` or you can issue `eb setenv key=value` CLI command to force the update.

Note that it is not the best practice to set environment variables via `.config` file. The reason is that environment variables are often of sensitive nature (credentials) and you may accidentally push this file to your code repository.

Comment: That's unfortunate that you can't update the values, but makes sense from a security perspective. And yes, my deployment server ingests the env vars so that they're never in source code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Environment variables ARE updated in the AWS console after changing them. I've just seen this for myself. Although my properties aren't reflecting the changes. Another AWS curiosity?

Comment: Interestingly (or unfortunately) I found that removing an environment var setting in a CDK app also doesn't change or remove it.  I had to destroy and redeploy the stack to remove a variable via CDK alone (ie not with EB CLI, which I assume would work).